# Powershell to Access Database, can't get IPaddress

Tags: database, ms-access, powershell

I am making an inventory PS script with access and everything is going well until I get to the network portion of my code.  For some reason that I must be overlooking or just do not know I cant get the fields to populate in the database.  Some will like the network card and device_name. But fields like IPaddress, subnetmask, default gateway, etc... will not return any value, when I check the database its blank.  I am confused and need some direction, any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Here is a snippet of my network function:

```
Function Update-Network {
"Updating Network Info"
foreach ($strComputer in $colComputers){
        $NetItems = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Comp $StrComputer | where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "True"}
    }
foreach ($objItem in $NetItems){
        $RecordSet.AddNew() 
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Device_Name") = $StrComputer
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Network_Card") = $objItem.Caption+" (enabled)"
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("DHCP_Enabled") = $objItem.DHCPEnabled
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("IP_Address") = $objItem.IPAddress
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Subnet_Mask") = $objItem.IPSubnet
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Default_Gateway") = $objItem.DefaultIPGateway
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("DNS_Servers") = $objItem.DNSServerSearchOrder
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("DNS_Reg") = $objItem.FullDNSRegistrationEnabled
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Primary_WINS") = $objItem.WINSPrimaryServer
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("Secondary_WINS") = $objItem.WINSSecondaryServer
        $RecordSet.Fields.Item("WINS_Lookup") = $objItem.WINSEnableLMHostsLookup
        $RecordSet.Update()
    }
} #End Update-Network
```

Comment: Does your powershell Update-Network return value you are expecting?

Comment: Have you verified that your script is picking up the data *to* insert into the database?

Comment: I forgot that I am working with arrays, so I needed to add [0] at the end of the objitem so that it will just give me the first in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your gwmi command, `IPAddress` is an array. I recommend munging it into a string explicitly. Try using:

```
$RecordSet.Fields.Item("IP_Address") = ($objItem.IPAddress -join ',')
```

Note you will want to do this on any field that may contain an array; IPAddress, IPSubnet, etc